# Running apollo server performance monitoring with prisma

Tags: apollo-server, prisma

For lack of guidance for how this can be done (and there's none on internet), maybe it could explained why this isn't possible?

Comment: Why wouldn't this be possible? For example, you can run GraphQL Yoga in combination with Apollo Engine: https://github.com/prismagraphql/graphql-yoga/blob/b70c744ff7274b23ec52f6c73102ea7004ebf522/examples/apollo-engine/index.js. Additionally, when you connect your Prisma server to Prisma Cloud you can see metrics there.

Comment: I saw some issue asking for performance monitoring, perhaps that was for graph cool, without this solution.